# Pandas dataframe iterating and comparing with state from previous row calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Source dataframe]

I would like to know how to vectorialize this logic:
create a new column (df['state']) that have value
'startTrade' if 10SMA>30SMA>100SMA but in preceding row this condition was not true
AND the previous row was not state='startTrade'.
Subsequest rows need to be state 'inTrade' or something like that.

'exitTrade' if 10SMA<30SMA and in previous row state was = 'inTrade'

I am coding that with python for-loop and is runninng, but I think that it would be very interesting knowing how to refers to the previous calculation results with lambda or any other way to vectorialize and using the philosophy of dataframe, and avoid python loop.

Comment: Are you familiar with `df.shift`?

Comment: Thank you very much Karl. Shift is very useful to have a "static" representation of a value existing at the preceeding row before starting. But every row calculation produce a new 'state' value that do not exists before. I would like to know how to get the result for the preceding row for the runtime calculation, not the value of a preexisting column.

Comment: It would greatly increase your chances of getting an answer if you provided some sample input and expected output data *as text, not as image* so people can copy and paste, cf. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the index attribute of the Dataframe :

df = pd.DataFrame(...)

for i in df.index:
    if df['10SMA'][i] > df['30SMA'][i] > df['100SMA'][i] and df['state'][i-1] != 'startTrade':
        df['state'][i] = 'startTrade'
    elif df['10SMA'][i] < df['30SMA'][i]:
        df['state'][i] = 'exitTrade'
    else:
        df['state'][i] = 'inTrade'
```

Comment: Thank you, but in the question I sad that I am using this approach to achive the same result. I am wondering if dataframe has a different way to vectorialize that calculation and so dramatically speed up the process, avoiding for loop in python.

Comment: What is the output of your test then ?

Comment: The autput for the Python script with for loop is on different dataframe. I don't like this way because this way doesn't use the full power of dataframe vectorialization.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the right answer is doing task in two times: first using shift, getting the previous row value on the current row. Then is possible to calulate every row in parallel mode, because every rows "knows" the previous row value. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel that understood the right answer even before I understood the question!!